# Do I need to check for Thread.isAlive() here?

Tags: java, multithreading

In a web controller, I have a parent thread that receives requests. Some requests take a long time to process. To prevent clients from timing out, I set up the parent thread to send back a byte every 2 seconds while a child thread is doing the time-consuming part of the operation.

I want to make sure I'm accounting for all possible cases of the child thread dying, but I also don't want to put in any extraneous checks.

Here is the parent thread:

```
    // This is my runnable class
    ProcessorRunnable runnable = new ProcessorRunnable(settings, Thread.currentThread());
    Thread childThread = new Thread(runnable);
    childThread.start();

    boolean interrupted = false;
    while (!runnable.done) { // <-- Check in question
        outputStream.write(' ');
        outputStream.flush();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // If the runnable is done, then this was an expected interrupt
            // Otherwise, remember the interruption and re-interrupt after processing is done
            // Or with self so that a later expected interrupt won't clear out an earlier unexpected one
            interrupted = interrupted || !runnable.done;
        }
    }
    if (runnable.runtimeException != null) {
        LOG.error("Propagating runtime exception from thread");
        throw runnable.runtimeException;
    }

    // ... Further processing on the results provided by the child thread
```

And here's ProcessorRunnable:

```
    private volatile boolean done;
    private volatile Result result;
    private volatile RuntimeException runtimeException;

    // ...

    public void run() {
        done = false;
        try {
            result = myService.timeConsumingOperation(settings);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            runtimeException = e;
        } finally {
            done = true;
            parentThread.interrupt();
        }
    }
```

My question is, would adding `&& Thread.isAlive()` check in the parent thread's main loop buy me anything?
It seems that setting `done = true` in the `finally` block should do the trick, but are there some cases where this child thread could die without notifying the parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `finally` in the child thread will always execute before it finishes. Even if that thread is interrupted or stopped, this happens via an exception that bubbles up the call stack and triggers all `finally`s. So, `done` will always be true if the child thread is interrupted.

For background tasks like this you may want to use an `ExecutorService` instead of raw threads. You can submit a `Runnable` to an `ExecutorService` and just call `get()` on the returned future to block until it is done. If you want to print out spaces while you are waiting, you can use a loop, calling the `get()` version with a timeout.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into `ExecutorService` as well. With the raw thread solution though, could an exception somehow happen before the `try` statement is reached, thus causing the `finally` to not get triggered?

Comment: @oksayt: In this case, no. The only statement before the `try` is the assignment to `done`, which cannot throw. Interruptions can only be thrown at very specific places (wait, sleep, etc). Technically, `Thread.stop()` might do it, but it is deprecated for exactly that reason.